# How to set low battery sound alert?

Tags: sound, battery

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
 Mostly I study from e-books, so I read e-books in fullscreen or play games in fullscreen. How to set a sound alert for low battery?

Comment: Check that question out. Does it answer your question?